# RESTEasy client: undeploy fails

Tags: java, resteasy

I have two two WARs running in different servers (probably in different machines as well). One of them (JVM1) hosts RESTful services using RESTEasy. The other one (JVM2) consumes the services using RESTEasy client.

The problem is that JAR files resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar & resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar are locked by server process during undeployment in JVM2. As a result undeploy task is failing.

I think that RESTEasy registers itself to some classloader. Is there any way of fixing this problem ? (I'm fine even with reflections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue (debugged the source code). It was the problem in the way jax-rs registers the providers. Disabling the auto registration and manually registering the providers did the trick.